# How to populate rows of a column with values from a different column

Tags: python, database, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with the columns holding opening and closing hours of restaurants. This dataset came from scraping a chinese restaurant guide, a little like tripAdvisor.

Please see the image attached for illustration

[image: Data Frame + trial code]

As you see, columns like 'Mon', and 'Fri', contain values, but some rows do not and thus the opening and closing hours are found in the 'Daily' column for the same restaurant.

Where the columns 'Mon' and 'Fri' have NaN values, I would like to populate them with the values from the the 'Daily' column.

The code that I have tested in the next line returns: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'.

Comment: don't post photos, post code

Answer (score -1):

[`pd.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) is one way:

```
df['Mon'] = df['Mon'].fillna(df['Daily'])
df['Fri'] = df['Fri'].fillna(df['Daily'])
```

Comment: @CamilleFeghali, if this answer helped feel free to accept (tick on left).